# Canvas: Click through images

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, keyevent

For an homework I wanted to make an interactive Story.
Basicly it is only click through images with the UP and DOWN button.
But my Problem is: 
My If function over writes the if function before

It should work like clicking through a gallery, so very simple, but I can´t find the solution...
`

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');     

var startImg = new Image();
startImg.onload = update;
startImg.src = 'img/start.png';

var eins = new Image();
eins.onload = update;
eins.src = 'img/1.png';

var zwei = new Image();
zwei.onload = update;
zwei.src = 'img/2.png';

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
console.log(e.keyCode);

if(e.keyCode == 38) {
    weiter('UP');
}
else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
    weiter('RIGHT');
}
else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
    weiter('DOWN');
}
else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
    weiter('LEFT');
}
}

function update() {

ctx.clearRect(0,0, 500,500);
ctx.drawImage(startImg, 0, 0, 500, 500);
} 


function weiter(dir){
    if(dir == 'UP') {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, 500,500);
        ctx.drawImage(eins, 0, 0, 500, 500);
        } 
context.closePath();
context.fill();

    if(dir == 'UP') {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, 500,500);
        ctx.drawImage(zwei, 0, 0, 500, 500);
        } 
context.closePath();
context.fill();
}
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a nice go at your idea, there are some things about it that causes your problems. When you have IF-statements, you need the program to stop when it has found a hit. That's where you use like that you did for your keylistener function.

There's also no need to closePath() on an image, nor filling it.

Here's a fiddle I made for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Niddro/u7qttjcn/

I've added several comments to explain what I did. I hope you can follow the logic. I also chose my own images =)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var currentImage = 0; //start at starting image as default

//Creating image library
var images = new Array();

images[0] = new Image(); //start image
images[0].src = 'http://minimotives.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Start_button_large.png';

images[1] = new Image(); //image 1
images[1].src = 'http://one_org_international.s3.amazonaws.com/international/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/one-logo-og-image.jpg';

images[2] = new Image(); //image 2
images[2].src = 'http://images.clipartpanda.com/number-2-clipart-11478-blue-number-two-clip-art.png';


window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    
    if(e.keyCode == 38) { //arrow up
        currentImage++; //go to next page
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 40) { //arrow down
        currentImage--; //go one page back
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 39) { //arrow right
        //do nothing
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 37) { //arrow left
        //do nothing
    }
    //Now we need to check to see if we are above or under the number of pages
    if (currentImage > images.length-1) {
        currentImage = images.length-1;
    }
    else if (currentImage < 0) {
         currentImage = 0;   
    }
    
    update(); //update the canvas after each keypress
}

//clear the canvas and draw image from library
function update() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(images[currentImage], 0, 0);
}

//At the end of everything, we need to call the update function to show the start image.
update();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" widht="600" height="600"></canvas>
```